# Lost focus after closing surfaceview activity

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a problem with my first project. I just have finished my first game in Android, but while I go back to main menu (main activity)  my app crashed with system error.

I have 3 activities:

1. menu
2. difficulty
3. game (Surface View realization)

When  I touch a back button in my game activity, it returns to main activity (menu) but the focus is gone off, and after few minutes the application crashed.

Can the reason be the surface view closing or maybe the rendering thread continue his work?

Comment: Whats the crash error (look in logcat)

Comment: I has looked for error in log cat. Its only one message that can be the reason for this bag:

Comment: couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view GoldenApps.Thockey.menu@40754398 has no id.